# How to stop ip hacking?

Tags: network

Some people I met in a chat room about 2 months ago hacked me and have been stalking me and sending me stupid messages ever since. I've recently formatted my computer (December 22) in an attempt to get rid of the intruders, but it didn't help.These people sent me another ridiculous message on a website that they couldn't have known I use, unless they had been seeing what I was doing on my pc or hacked my email--which, by the way, is a new random email I created after formatting, just like the profile I made on that website I just mentioned.

I think they have hacked me via ip. Maybe they have exploited some vulnerabilities on my computer and used them to remotely access it. Anyway, I don't know exactly what they are doing, but I would like to stop it. How can I block them so that they can no longer attack my computer and spy on me again?

Comment: Very vague question.

Comment: This is very vague, please provide a more detailed description of what happened (ofc omit names of sites etc).
Example: "I get popups on my computer even when not browsing the web.", "Everytime I post something on forum x I get spam."
Also "hacked me via ip"? This doesn't show much knowledge of IS, which is fine in and of itself but do not try to pretend such knowledge then.

Comment: Indeed very vague question. Hacking never happens by magic.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the worst case scenario: they managed to take over your computer, with full access. Some of the steps below are overkill but if you are not sure that you have done a complete assessment you are better off planning for the worst.

Before cleaning up your computer you must ensure nobody can get to it. Do all the operations below from another computer (not one of yours that was in your network) or a phone.

- If you have an internet box make sure that none of "administrative panels" are available form Internet (this is usually a setting on your box)
- If you have set up remote access to your computer (LogMeIn, Teamviewer, ...) change the passwords.
- Change the password of your main email account as it is usually the sink where all requests for password changes are sent. Set multifactor authentication if available.

Now you have to clean your computer (=reinstall it from scratch, not from a backup) and ensure it is up to date.

You have to assess what you have done with your computer, specifically the sites you went to and logged into. Change all passwords for these accounts. Whatever you have done on your computer may have been logged - this includes credit card number or other sensitive information.

If you have other computers within your network, reinstall them as well.

For the future, beside not accepting everything which comes in, have a different password for each of your accounts (use a password manager) and keep all your devices updated.

I may have missed something, I will update this answer if necessary.